# How to create a joystick/controller widget in PyQt?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I want to create a joystick widget similar to this

[image]

My current implementation uses `QToolButton()` for the side arrows but I'm not sure how to create the circle in the middle. When the user clicks on the middle point and drags it towards an arrow, it should register the movement. I'm thinking about using `paintEvent()` and `drawEclipse()` or maybe even `QDial()` but I'm not sure how to do this.

[image]

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys

class JoystickWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(JoystickWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.field_joystick_up_button = QtGui.QToolButton()
        self.field_joystick_up_button.setArrowType(QtCore.Qt.UpArrow)
        self.field_joystick_up_button.clicked.connect(self.joystick_up)
        self.field_joystick_up_button.setFixedWidth(75)
        self.field_joystick_down_button = QtGui.QToolButton()
        self.field_joystick_down_button.setArrowType(QtCore.Qt.DownArrow)
        self.field_joystick_down_button.clicked.connect(self.joystick_down)
        self.field_joystick_down_button.setFixedWidth(75)
        self.field_joystick_right_button = QtGui.QToolButton()
        self.field_joystick_right_button.setArrowType(QtCore.Qt.RightArrow)
        self.field_joystick_right_button.clicked.connect(self.joystick_right)
        self.field_joystick_right_button.setFixedWidth(75)
        self.field_joystick_left_button = QtGui.QToolButton()
        self.field_joystick_left_button.setArrowType(QtCore.Qt.LeftArrow)
        self.field_joystick_left_button.clicked.connect(self.joystick_left)
        self.field_joystick_left_button.setFixedWidth(75)

        self.joystick_layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.joystick_layout.addWidget(self.field_joystick_up_button,alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.joystick_layout_row = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.joystick_layout_row.addWidget(self.field_joystick_left_button)
        self.joystick_layout_row.addWidget(self.field_joystick_right_button)
        self.joystick_layout.addLayout(self.joystick_layout_row)
        self.joystick_layout.addWidget(self.field_joystick_down_button,alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

    def get_joystick_layout(self):
        return self.joystick_layout
    def joystick_up(self):
        print("Up")
    def joystick_down(self):
        print("Down")
    def joystick_right(self):
        print("Right")
    def joystick_left(self):
        print("Left")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Create main application window
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    app.setStyle(QtGui.QStyleFactory.create("Cleanlooks"))
    mw = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    mw.setWindowTitle('Joystick example')

    # Create and set widget layout
    # Main widget container
    cw = QtGui.QWidget()
    ml = QtGui.QGridLayout()
    cw.setLayout(ml)
    mw.setCentralWidget(cw)

    # Create joystick 
    joystick = JoystickWidget()

    ml.addLayout(joystick.get_joystick_layout(),0,0)

    mw.show()

    ## Start Qt event loop unless running in interactive mode or using pyside.
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

Sometimes, it's easier to start from scratch.

If you use `QWidget::mousePressEvent()`, `QWidget::mouseReleaseEvent()`, `QWidget::mouseMoveEvent()` and `QWidget::paintEvent()`, you will be able to handle your joystick.

Use `QWidget::paintEvent()` to draw your joystick at the center of your widget.

`QWidget::mousePressEvent()` will be called whenever the use press a button his mouse. You can use it the start the moving of your joystick.

`QWidget::mouseReleaseEvent()` is called when the user release the mouse button. Use it to reset the joystick.

`QWidget::mouseMoveEvent()` is called the the mouse is moving. Use it to compute the offset of the joystick and the direction (up, left, down or right). If you want some kind of analog joystick, you can also use the distance between the center and the joystick to get a number between 0 (no moving) and 1 (at the maximum).

For example:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
import sys
from enum import Enum

class Direction(Enum):
    Left = 0
    Right = 1
    Up = 2
    Down = 3

class Joystick(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Joystick, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setMinimumSize(100, 100)
        self.movingOffset = QPointF(0, 0)
        self.grabCenter = False
        self.__maxDistance = 50

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        bounds = QRectF(-self.__maxDistance, -self.__maxDistance, self.__maxDistance * 2, self.__maxDistance * 2).translated(self._center())
        painter.drawEllipse(bounds)
        painter.setBrush(Qt.black)
        painter.drawEllipse(self._centerEllipse())

    def _centerEllipse(self):
        if self.grabCenter:
            return QRectF(-20, -20, 40, 40).translated(self.movingOffset)
        return QRectF(-20, -20, 40, 40).translated(self._center())

    def _center(self):
        return QPointF(self.width()/2, self.height()/2)


    def _boundJoystick(self, point):
        limitLine = QLineF(self._center(), point)
        if (limitLine.length() > self.__maxDistance):
            limitLine.setLength(self.__maxDistance)
        return limitLine.p2()

    def joystickDirection(self):
        if not self.grabCenter:
            return 0
        normVector = QLineF(self._center(), self.movingOffset)
        currentDistance = normVector.length()
        angle = normVector.angle()

        distance = min(currentDistance / self.__maxDistance, 1.0)
        if 45 <= angle < 135:
            return (Direction.Up, distance)
        elif 135 <= angle < 225:
            return (Direction.Left, distance)
        elif 225 <= angle < 315:
            return (Direction.Down, distance)
        return (Direction.Right, distance)


    def mousePressEvent(self, ev):
        self.grabCenter = self._centerEllipse().contains(ev.pos())
        return super().mousePressEvent(ev)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.grabCenter = False
        self.movingOffset = QPointF(0, 0)
        self.update()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.grabCenter:
            print("Moving")
            self.movingOffset = self._boundJoystick(event.pos())
            self.update()
        print(self.joystickDirection())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Create main application window
    app = QApplication([])
    app.setStyle(QStyleFactory.create("Cleanlooks"))
    mw = QMainWindow()
    mw.setWindowTitle('Joystick example')

    # Create and set widget layout
    # Main widget container
    cw = QWidget()
    ml = QGridLayout()
    cw.setLayout(ml)
    mw.setCentralWidget(cw)

    # Create joystick 
    joystick = Joystick()

    # ml.addLayout(joystick.get_joystick_layout(),0,0)
    ml.addWidget(joystick,0,0)

    mw.show()

    ## Start Qt event loop unless running in interactive mode or using pyside.
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

You can use the same logic to create the buttons: define four areas for your buttons and check when the mouse is pressed in these areas.

Comment: Got the error `NameError: name 'QWidget' is not defined` when trying to recreate the same using PyQt5.

Comment: `QWidget` has been moved in another module since Qt5. Add the line `from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget`